# pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am running some code on an embedded board that uses an ARM processor. I have declared this array of strings.

```
const int8_t *test_str[][3] = {
{"pa4",  "3", "A0"},
{"pa5",  "3", "A1"},
{"pa6",  "3", "A1"},};
```

I am testing the code on another ARM processor from a different manufacturer and got no compile warnings. But if I compile it with the board that I am going to use I get the following warning

pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness

The board is an ST32F0 ARM device. Have I actually missed something out of the declaration?

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `int8_t` with `char` and see if you get the same warning.

Comment: @GovindParmar unlikely he will. Probably `char` is unsigned on this compiler (can easily find out by looking at `CHAR_MIN`).

Comment: Actually using char removed the warning. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A string literal in C has type `char[len]`, where `len` represents the number of characters in the literal plus one for null termination.

Since `char` could be either signed or unsigned, you cannot make a portable code that forces pointers produced from string literals into either `int8_t` or `uint8_t` without an additional cast.

Changing `const int8_t` to `const char` will make pointer types match, but the type of the elements would no longer be `int8_t`.

Comment: It seems that int8_t is defined as signed char.

Comment: @user3047110 Correct, and `uint8_t` is defined as unsigned. `char`, however, could be either signed or unsigned, depending on your system, and string literals will be `char` arrays. Hence, the signed/unsigned qualifier will be matched.